# I've written a query and now I get this error "Incorrect syntax near '<'."

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 
    SUM(a.totalsales) AS TotalSale,
    SUM(a.cfee) + SUM(b.fee) * (TotalSale <> 0)
FROM 
    [dbo].[tbl1] AS a
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[tbl2] AS b ON a.[code] = b.[code]
WHERE 
    a.ID = '1234';
```

I'm getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '<'

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `TotalSale <>0` bit? That makes no sense.

Comment: Count your brackets.

Comment: You have an extra right parenthesis (`)`) after `<>0` too (but like David said, having a boolean expression in the `SELECT` makes no sense).

Comment: totalsale can't be used there.

Comment: Also the condition `<> 0'  should be in `where` condition.

Comment: As you can see, there's lots of problems here. Tell us what you're *actually* trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you need  condition on aggretated result then use HAVING

```
    SELECT SUM(a.totalsales) AS TotalSale,
    ISNULL(SUM(a.cfee) + SUM(b.fee)* SUM(a.totalsales),0) tot
    FROM [dbo].[tbl1] AS a
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl2] AS b
    ON a.[code]= b.[code]
    WHERE a.ID= '1234'
    HAVING SUM(a.totalsales) <>0;
```

and you can't use column name alias in select clause  you must repeat the code

Comment: answer  updated ..

Comment: I replaced TotalSale with SUM(a.totalsales), query is working fine. but returned NULL in second column, i am expecting 0.

Comment: @programming_123  answer  updated  with isnull()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT SUM(a.totalsales) AS TotalSale,
              (SUM(a.cfee)
              +
              SUM(b.fee)* SUM(a.totalsales) ) as sm
FROM [dbo].[tbl1] AS a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl2] AS b
ON a.[code]= b.[code]
WHERE a.ID= '1234'
having SUM(a.totalsales)<>0;
```

I hope it helps

Comment: i have already edited the answer try it again

Comment: try it again, i already modified it.

Comment: Query returned NULL in second column, i am expecting 0 instead of NULL in output

Comment: have you checked the values of cfee and fee and make sure that they are not null.

Comment: I am having an another issue, this is part of the above query. Query is "SELECT FORMAT(SUM(CAST(a.[fee] AS FLOAT)), 'C') AS AdminFees FROM dbo.tbl1". It's working fine. i am getting right exact negative value. but due to format function the negative value converted into positive.

Comment: If the NULL result is correct, and you need to see 0 instead of NULL, then use COALESCE or ISNULL function to convert null value to 0

Comment: Why don't you post an entire query?

Comment: Please edit an original question to add issues related to it so we can help you.